# struct memory allocation (leaks and crash, profiling on iPhone)

Tags: objective-c, c, memory-management, struct, profiling

I have a struct defined as:

```
struct VImage
{
    uint8_t *imageData;
    int dimensions[3];
    ...
}
```

I was profiling my code to look for leaks and other issues. Consider the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    // after we have the image, we use the cheap rgb function to get rgb data
    struct VImage *vImage = [SomeClass someFunction:someArgument];
    free(vImage);
}
```

This crashes my code. And I am wondering why that is the case. The condition `i < 10` however doesn't crash the app. Profiling on instruments doesn't show that there is any leak; however the allocations spike and I am using a lot of live memory; so I am wondering if freeing the struct in this way is right OR if free is an async function that will free the memory at someone, but not just when I would ask it to.

EDIT: So I have been asked to provide details for this `someFunction` method and I will. I think there is no memory leak in the method but nonetheless, I will put it here:

```
+ (struct VImage *)grayScaleImageDataFromImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    int imageWidth = image.size.width, imageHeight = image.size.height;

    uint32_t *rgbImageData = (uint32_t *) malloc(imageWidth * imageHeight * sizeof(uint32_t));
    memset(rgbImageData, 0, imageWidth * imageHeight * sizeof(uint32_t));

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    // create context with RGBA pixels
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rgbImageData, imageWidth, imageHeight, 8, imageWidth * sizeof(uint32_t), colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast);
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
    CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, NO);

    // paint to fill pixels array
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight), [image CGImage]);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    // now convert to grayscale using CCIR 601 <=> Y' = 0.299 R' + 0.587 G' + 0.114 B'.
    uint8_t *grayScaleImageData = (uint8_t *) malloc(imageWidth * imageHeight);
    for(int y = 0; y < imageHeight; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < imageWidth; x++)
        {
            uint32_t rgbPixel = rgbImageData[y*imageWidth+x];
            grayScaleImageData[y*imageWidth + x] = 0.299*((rgbPixel>>24)&255) + 0.587*((rgbPixel>>16)&255) + 0.114*((rgbPixel>>8)&255);
        }
    }

    struct VImage *vImage = createGrayScaleDescription(grayScaleImageData, imageHeight, imageWidth);

    free(rgbImageData);
    return vImage;
}

struct VImage *createGrayScaleDescription(uint8_t *grayScaleImage, int height, int width)
{
    struct VImage *vImage = malloc(sizeof(struct VImage));
    vImage->grayScaleImage = grayScaleImage;
    vImage->numberOfDimensions = 2;
    vImage->dimensions[0] = height, vImage->dimensions[1] = width, vImage->dimensions[2] = 1;
    vImage->isGrayscale = true;
    return vImage;
}
```

So all I am doing is creating a grayscale image using rgb data by doing some computation. However, I don't think there's any problem here.

Comment: That depends on the implementation of `someFunction`. Can you share its code?

Comment: Post the code for `someFunction:someArgument:`?

Comment: @Zaph it has no relation to the question in the link you provided. @Merlevede, I have posted the code for `someFunction`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing, you are leaking the memory pointed to by `grayScaleImageData`:

In grayScaleImageDataFromImage you do

```
uint8_t *grayScaleImageData = (uint8_t *) malloc(imageWidth * imageHeight);
```

which is fine, then in `createGrayScaleDescription` you set `vImage->grayScaleImage` to point to that memory, which is also fine.

But then in your 1 to 100 loop, you free vImage without freeing the memory pointed to by `vImage->grayScaleImage` first.  That is a memory leak.

I don't think that should be crashing your application, but it is something you need to fix.  Nothing else jumps out at me, but I'll take a closer look.

**EDIT**:  On closer inspection, it looks like you are overrunning the buffer you allocated for 
 `grayScaleImageData`.

You malloc it with:

```
uint8_t *grayScaleImageData = (uint8_t *) malloc(imageWidth * imageHeight);
```

but then you fill that buffer with:

```
uint32_t rgbPixel = rgbImageData[y*imageWidth+x];
grayScaleImageData[y*imageWidth + x] = 0.299*((rgbPixel>>24)&255) + 0.587*((rgbPixel>>16)&255) + 0.114*((rgbPixel>>8)&255);
```

You've allocated (imageWidth * imageHeight) 8-bit uints, but then you fill it with 32-bit uints.

Perhaps that is what is causing you to crash?  Maybe try changing that malloc to

```
uint32_t *grayScaleImageData = (uint32_t *) malloc(imageWidth * imageHeight * sizeof (uint32_t));
```

as you did above for rgbImageData?  That, or cast the result of your bit shifting calculations to a uint8_t before setting it into grayScaleImageData:

```
uint32_t rgbPixel = rgbImageData[y*imageWidth+x];
grayScaleImageData[y*imageWidth + x] = (uint8_t)(0.299*((rgbPixel>>24)&255) + 0.587*((rgbPixel>>16)&255) + 0.114*((rgbPixel>>8)&255));
```

Comment: So before you answered this, I researched more and found out exactly what you were saying. However, I think free(vImage) does the job but I need to free the memory pointed by `grayScaleImage` before returning the `vImage` from the method. That's how I am fighting it right now. I don't think freeing `vImage->grayScaleImage` is the right thing to do. Can you comment if this is the right approach?

Comment: @flippex17: You can't free that memory until you're done with it, so no.  I've edited my answer to add what I think is the real problem.  As for the memory leak, you need to free(vImage->grayScaleImage) right before you free(vImage).

Comment: So grayScaleImageData doesn't need that much information. I don't think I am overrunning the buffer as it should crash every time I run it. I only input [y*imageWidth + x] values that's capped at imageWidth*imageHeight. Further, those shifts and masks are all 8 bits; so the computation is all 8 bits. I'll try your solution though.

Comment: @flippex17:  Only the last one overruns the buffer, by exactly 3 bytes.  The result of the bit shift calculation is a number that fits in 8 bits, but it is still a 32-bit calculation.  The end result is a 32-bit number whose upper 24 bits are zero.  Buffer overruns only cause a crash if they overwrite something important, so it might not  crash every time.

Comment: That is actually true. This would a buffer overflow. I don't want to have a 32-bit grayScaleImageData though so I would need to constrain the calculation such that its 8-bit only. I am happy to lose some information though.

Comment: Well again, how is that a 32-bit calculation?

Comment: @flippex17: Try casting the result of the calculation to a uint8_t, as I said in the last suggestion above.  It's a 32-bit calculation because you are doing the calculation on a 32-bit uint.  The result of that calculation is a number that fits in 8 bits, but since rgbPixel is a 32 bit quantity, the result of the calculation is a 32-bit quantity.  If you cast the result to a uint8_t, you'll strip off the high 24 bits (which are zero anyway), giving you an 8-bit number that fits in 8 bits.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48310/discussion-between-flippex17-and-jeff-loughlin)